# Favorite Tags - excluding tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching, ignored-tags, tag-search

Favorite Tags works well to jump straight to required lists, but there is need of multiple tags filtering with expressions.

This is achievable in search box, e.g. [`[webgl] -[three.js]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webgl+-three.js).
But those extremely useful filtering features are not supported in favorite tags.

If this is something possible to be added anytime in the future, and if people believe that this is handy?

UPD:
Ignored Tags, almosts do what is required but it only fades out the questions that matches ignored tag, while if you search with query as above, then it filters off those tags as well.

Comment: On the main Stack Exchange site, there is option to create "Filtered Questions" - I believe that's what you want. [Click here](http://stackexchange.com/filters/new) to create new filter, you can add rules and in each rule choose one tag. This supports only "OR" though, hope it's good enough?

Comment: No. It does not allow to `filter off` (exclude) tags from search. But thanks for link.

Answer (score 2):

Favorite tags are used for highlighting the posts tagged with those tags which we added as favorite.

I think adding favorite tags is not focus on jumping to the questions of those tags, this can be done by clicking on that tag in the tag list or bookmark that page(tagged questions page).

Comment: Highlight - is one of the ways, but clicking on that tag, will filter off the list of questions, it actually acts the same way as search above (even puts tag in [ ]). Updated the question above.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't exactly answer your request, but a not-so-cool way is to bookmark your query

Basically you just search normally with the search box then you bookmark the resulting link.

For example, your query would generate this bookmark-able search link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webgl+-three.js

Comment: Yep, it is exactly the link I've shared from the question above :)
Technically, there is a way of writing custom script, that would insert stuff in front-end, and apply that script through Chrome Extension, but, can't be bothered :D

Comment: Yes, I agree that having it built-in in SO/SE would be much more convenient.